# Error Trying to Load DefaultNLP Model in Stanford.NLP.CoreNLP .Net in WebAPI C# Project

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, owin, stanford-nlp

I have been attempting to load the default models I pulled from the suggested ZIP file. Generally, I am loading the annotation into a singleton at the application level so the resources can be shared across all sessions. (in WebAPI OWIN Startup, this is being called from startup.cs).

Trying other methods with relative path references, I was getting this error:

> unable to resolve
>   "edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger"
>   as either class path, filename or URL

I am not sure if I am getting closer to or further from a solution. **This is at the root directory of my ASP.NET WebAPI Project:**

[image]

However, I am getting the error:

> Unhandled Execution Error
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException:
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 43:                 // We should change current directory, so
>   StanfordCoreNLP could find all the model files automatically Line 44: 
>   Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(ModelLocation));
>   Line 45:                 pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props); Line
>   46:             } Line 47:             finally
>
> Source File: D:\xxx\xxx\xxx\NLP.cs    Line: 45
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvocationTargetException]    __(Object[] ) +444
>   FastConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Object[] args) +28
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Object[] initargs, CallerID
>   ) +133    edu.stanford.nlp.util.ClassFactory.createInstance(Object[]
>   params) +108
>
> [ClassCreationException: MetaClass couldn't create public
>   edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorImpl(java.lang.String,java.util.Properties)
>   with args [sutime, {}]]
>   edu.stanford.nlp.util.ClassFactory.createInstance(Object[] params)
>   +372    edu.stanford.nlp.util.MetaClass.createInstance(Object[] objects) +34
>   edu.stanford.nlp.util.ReflectionLoading.loadByReflection(String
>   className, Object[] arguments) +71
>
> [ReflectionLoadingException: Error creating
>   edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorImpl]
>   edu.stanford.nlp.util.ReflectionLoading.loadByReflection(String
>   className, Object[] arguments) +232
>   edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorFactory.create(String
>   className, String name, Properties props) +80
>   edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorFactory.createExtractor(String
>   name, Properties props) +34
>   edu.stanford.nlp.ie.regexp.NumberSequenceClassifier..ctor(Properties
>   props, Boolean useSUTime, Properties sutimeProps) +57
>   edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERClassifierCombiner..ctor(Boolean
>   applyNumericClassifiers, Boolean useSUTime, Properties nscProps,
>   String[] loadPaths) +129
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorImplementations.ner(Properties
>   properties) +454    edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.6.create() +46
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(String name) +163
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(Properties ,
>   Boolean , AnnotatorImplementations ) +555
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP..ctor(Properties props,
>   Boolean enforceRequirements) +55
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP..ctor(Properties props) +76 
>   XXX.XXX.NLP.Start(String modelLocation) in
>   D:\xxx\xxx\xxx\NLP.cs:45
>   XXX.XXX.Startup.Configuration(IAppBuilder app) in
>   D:\xxx\xxx\xxx\Startup.cs:16
>
> [TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of
>   aninvocation.]    System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object
>   target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +128
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   +146    Owin.Loader.<>c__DisplayClass12.b__b(IAppBuilder builder) +93
>   Owin.Loader.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(IAppBuilder
>   builder) +209
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinAppContext.Initialize(Action 1
>   startup) +843
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinBuilder.Build(Action 1 startup) +51 
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.InitializeBlueprint()
>   +101    System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore(T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func 1 valueFactory)
>   +141    Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication
>   context) +172
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +618
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +419
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +343
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target
>   of an invocation.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +579
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +120    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +712

Here is the code I have (NLP.Start() is called in startup.cs):

```
public static class NLP
{
    private static string _modelLocation = @"~\NLPModels";
    public static string ModelLocation
    {
        set
        {
            NLP.Start(value);
        }
        get
        {
            return _modelLocation;
        }
    }
    private static StanfordCoreNLP pipeline;
    public static void Start(string modelLocation = null)
    {
        var curDir = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(modelLocation))
        {
            _modelLocation = modelLocation;
        }
        try
        {
            // Annotation pipeline configuration
            var props = new Properties();
            props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
            props.setProperty("sutime.binders", "0");
            // We should change current directory, so StanfordCoreNLP could find all the model files automatically
            Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(ModelLocation));
            pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
        }
        finally
        {
            Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(curDir);
        }
    }

    public static JObject ProcessText(string text)
    {
        var annotation = new Annotation(text);
        using (java.io.StringWriter writer = new java.io.StringWriter())
        {
            pipeline.jsonPrint(annotation, writer);
            return JObject.Parse(writer.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After poking around a bit, I found the solution of the same problem.

https://github.com/sergey-tihon/Stanford.NLP.NET/issues/11

If you aren't willing to read through the thread, here was the basic answer. Amend this line of code

```
props.setProperty("sutime.binders", "0");
```

to

```
props.setProperty("ner.useSUTime", "0");
```